# Cloud9 IDE Not Loading Jquery

Tags: jquery, cloud9-ide

I have tried many ways of importing Jquery into my project but I can never get it to work in Cloud9. My code works on other IDEs and text editors, but not on Cloud9. If any body knows more than me about this please help. Here is my project: [CLOUD9 PROJECT](https://ide.c9.io/themejared_1/themeteam)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always useful to open the browser developer tools/console for more information.
In this case it says:

`[blocked] The page at '...' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://codepen.io/assets/libs/fullpage/jquery.js': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.`

There is your answer. For your convenience I modified it for you.

Comment: This is the right answer. Change the include to: `<script src="//codepen.io/assets/libs/fullpage/jquery.js">`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you've run into a bug on cloud9. Please email support@c9.io and we'll work with you to get this fixed.